# AutoTex error with missfont.log on arXiv?

Tags: fonts, arxiv

I am uploading a large thesis to arXiv, and it fails, returning this error at the end:

```
Output written on finalv1.pdf (122 pages, 6984498 bytes).
Transcript written on finalv1.log.

[verbose]: LaTeX wrote a .toc, .lof, or .lot file - running extra passes
[verbose]: WARNING: Reached max number of passes, possibly failed to get CROSS-REFERENCES right.
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'finalv1.lot' (1477591907 >= 1477591878)
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'finalv1.out' (1477591907 >= 1477591878)
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'finalv1.toc' (1477591907 >= 1477591878)
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'finalv1.aux' (1477591907 >= 1477591878)
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'finalv1.lof' (1477591907 >= 1477591878)
[verbose]: now stamping pdf file 'finalv1.pdf' with stamp 'arXiv:submit/1704978 [math.PR] 27 Oct 2016'
[verbose]: stamped pdf file
[error]: missfont.log present.
*** AutoTeX ABORTING ***

[verbose]: AutoTeX returned error: missfont.log present.

[verbose]: $autotex->process failed $@: $?: 0 $!: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[verbose]: Error running AutoTeX process:
```

I think it relates to missfont.log, which is created when there is an error with fonts...but I don't use any unusual fonts. Is there some way to fix this?

Full output info: [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=18913211715620226743)

Comparison output from my PC: [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=13178483305754755689)

And without hyperref error: [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=93948383506165422932)

Note: It compiles fine on my ubuntu pc with new installation of tex, no problems at all.

also, the document preamble looks like this

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{calligra}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{xcolor}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,left=1.5in,right=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0,0,0},pdfauthor={Alexander Kartun-Giles}, colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{graphicx,amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amscd,bezier,amstext,makeidx,mathtools,xcolor,siunitx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}

\raggedbottom
%\doublespacing
\onehalfspacing
\definecolor{apricot}{RGB}{253, 213, 177}
\newcommand{\bi}{\boldsymbol{i}}
\newcommand{\bj}{\boldsymbol{j}}
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Alph{part}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thechapter.\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}
\newcommand{\RR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\QQ}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\CC}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\NN}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\EE}{\mathbb{E}}
\newcommand{\FF}{\mathbb{F}}
\newcommand{\F}{{\cal{F}}}
\newcommand{\sym}{\mbox{sym}}
\newcommand{\modd}{\text{~mod~}}
\newcommand{\RRe}{\text{Re}}
\newcommand{\IIm}{\text{Im}}
\newcommand{\Neff}{N_{\rm eff}}
\newcommand{\FDelta}{{\cal{F}}_{\Delta}}
\newcommand{\FD}{{\cal{F}}_{D}}
\newcommand{\FE}{{\cal{F}}_{E}}
\newcommand{\FDp}{{\cal{F}}_D^+}
\newcommand{\FDm}{{\cal{F}}_D^-} 
\newcommand*{\reff}[1]{(\ref{#1})}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\singlenorm{|}{|}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\providecommand{\floor}[1]{\left \lfloor #1 \right \rfloor }
\providecommand{\ceil}[1]{\left \lceil #1 \right \rceil }
\providecommand{\ex}[1]{\mathbb{E}\left( #1 \right)}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}
\DeclareMathOperator{\csch}{csch}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsec}{arcsec}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccot}{arccot}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccsc}{arccsc}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccosh}{arcosh}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsinh}{arcsinh}
%\DeclareMathOperator{\arccos}{arccos}
%\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsin}{arcsin}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arctanh}{arctanh}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsech}{arcsech}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccsch}{arcsch}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccoth}{arcoth}


\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{theorem}[lemma]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[lemma]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{identity}[lemma]{Identity}
\newtheorem{remark}[lemma]{Remark}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[lemma]{Conjecture}
\numberwithin{equation}{section} \numberwithin{lemma}{section}
\newenvironment{example}[1][Example]{\begin{trivlist}
  \item[\hskip \labelsep {\bfseries #1}]}{\end{trivlist}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\contraction}[5][1ex]{%
  \mathchoice
      {\contraction@\displaystyle{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#1}}%
      {\contraction@\textstyle{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#1}}%
      {\contraction@\scriptstyle{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#1}}%
      {\contraction@\scriptscriptstyle{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#1}}}%
\newcommand{\contraction@}[6]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$#1#2$}%
  \setbox2=\hbox{$#1#3$}%
  \setbox4=\hbox{$#1#4$}%
  \setbox6=\hbox{$#1#5$}%
  \dimen0=\wd2%
  \advance\dimen0 by \wd6%
  \divide\dimen0 by 2%
  \advance\dimen0 by \wd4%
  \vbox{%
    \hbox to 0pt{%
      \kern \wd0%
      \kern 0.5\wd2%
      \contraction@@{\dimen0}{#6}%
      \hss}%
    \vskip 0.2ex%
    \vskip\ht2}}
\newcommand{\contracted}[5][1ex]{%
  \contraction[#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}\ensuremath{#2#3#4#5}}
\newcommand{\contraction@@}[3][0.06em]{%
  \hbox{%
    \vrule width #1 height 0pt depth #3%
    \vrule width #2 height 0pt depth #1%
    \vrule width #1 height 0pt depth #3%
    \relax}}
\newcommand{\ch}{}
\newcommand{\Vk}{V}

\definecolor{deepred}{RGB}{209,34,80}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{18,194,15}
\definecolor{amber}{RGB}{222,194,13}
\definecolor{darkergreen}{RGB}{0,133,0}
\definecolor{betagreen}{RGB}{128,255,128}
\definecolor{hotpink}{RGB}{85,26,139}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\linespread{1.15}
\begin{document}
```

Comment: Is there no more information, like the actual compilation log, that would tell us more

Comment: I think it is too large to add as a code snippet?

Comment: Then go through it to see if it reports any font errors. As it stands now we cannot help due to lack of information

Comment: I have added a link to the full arXiv output (link now fixed).

Comment: The log looks like there might be multiple problems. To start at the first compilation, it crashes with `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.` How are you calling this package?

Comment: Can you post the log file from your pc as a comparison?

Comment: Have removed, but arxiv still has an error!

Comment: Remember that arxiv (on purpose) use an older latex installation

Comment: Still, just cannot get clear info: the output file is apparently created

Comment: I'm guessing lmodern in your doc. Also can we have an arxiv log where the hyperref error have been fixed?

Comment: In systems like this latex usually run in non-stop mode or similar. Thus tries to make a guess at each error. Thus there is output even when there are errors

Comment: Added log without hyperref error. Also, removed lmodern package, but same errors.

Comment: Thanks! You like to collect packages, don't you? Some are loaded 3 times, like `graphicx`

Comment: sorry about this disgrace of a preamble, its part of someone elses template. It has worked on arXiv before, also works on my pc. Maybe if I tidy this up?

Comment: The only problem I see with you preamble is `Invalid value '0,0,0'(hyperref) for option 'pdfborder'.` Otherwise I am out of ideas.

Comment: Have removed this since then. It must be some sort of font error I don't understand. I will rewrite the preamble tomorrow!

Comment: You should clean up the preamble if you use it, even if it isn't yours. `hyperref` should be loaded last except for packages which specifically need to load later.  Why do you have `\makeatletter` without `\makeatother`? If you need to link files, please use a pastebin type site so people don't have to download them.

Comment: Try to remove the microtype package. According to your log you are using it. Had the same error, this solved the same issue in my case.

Comment: @rralf cleaning up the preamble has sorted it, so this may have been the problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments.